# Event when view has been re-rendered

Tags: ember.js

I have a custom View extending Ember.view with a template binded to a model:

```
template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div >{{view.content.label}}</div>')
```

I would like to use a callback or event when the view has been updated (and not when the model has been changed).
This callback (pre-rendered event by example) could use the width of this view and make some actions based on this new size.

Is there a solution with Ember framework ?

Answer (score 0):

The `didInsertElement` event might be what you are looking for:

> "Called when the element of the view has been inserted into the DOM.
>   Override this function to do any set up that requires an element in
>   the document."

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement

There is also `willInsertElement`.

Comment: Your proposal is not working because in my case the Dom node has been already inserted and only the div content is modified... I need to be triggered when the div content is modified ({{view.content.label}})

Answer (score 0):

similar to `didInsertElement` there is the `willClearRender` event too which is fired just before the view gets rerendered.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willClearRender